# how to remove the file after download in specified path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
 filepath = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@filename)
  # puts" #{:@filename}"
    qget = params['clientquery']
    if !qget.nil? then
 begin
   systemCmd = "bash /home/abc/t.sh \"#{qget}\" \"#{filepath}\""
  puts systemCmd
  output = system("#{systemCmd} 2>&1")
  data = File.read(filepath)
  send_data data, filename: File.basename(filepath),
                    type: 'application/csv',
                   disposition: 'attachment'
 ensure
 # delfile = File.basename("/tmp/download.csv")
  FileUtils.remove_entry_secure File.basename("/tmp/download.csv")
 # File.delete(delfile) 
 # redirect_to '/report'
  end
```

FileUtils.remove_entry_secure File.basename("/tmp/download.csv") using this code i try to remove file after downloading but it not working

if i  comment the line  FileUtils.remove_entry_secure File.basename("/tmp/download.csv")

The file downloaded but i want remove that file after download the file

Comment: whats the error that you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

I think permission problem.could you please verify permission for `/tmp` folder.

because `FileUtils.remove_entry_secure` method will check all permission,user and group and it will remove.

Please refer [click here](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/remove%5fentry%5fsecure)